# Kotlin Worker Pool - Long Running Kotlin Coroutine and Java Heap OutOfMemory

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm trying to replicate a Worker Pool in Kotlin: https://gobyexample.com/worker-pools

It works wonderful, but my problem is that I get OutOfMemoryError because all object references from the worker coroutines are kept in the heap as long as the coroutine is running. How can I avoid this problem?

Here is my code:

I create a channel in Service A and receive the data everytime a channel object is received.

```
class ServiceA(
) {

    val channel = Channel<Pair<String,ByteArray>>(10000)

    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.Default)

    @PostConstruct
    fun createWorkerGroup(){
        coroutineScope.launch{
            for(x in 1..5){
                launch {
                    println("Create Worker $x")
                    while (true){
                            uploadImage(channel.receive() )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
 private suspend fun uploadImage(urlAndImage: Pair<String, ByteArray>){
            val (url,image) = urlAndImage
            println("Uploading Image: $url")

    }
```

In my controller method I send my data to a channel:

```
uploadService.channel.send(Pair(url, image.bytes))
```

Comment: Do one or more of the following: 1) Increase the memory limit, 2) Limit the number of threads in the pool (don't start a new task until a previous one is finished and removed from memory), 3) Don't infinitely store images in memory, only store what is needed for the task at hand (path only?), although this will only delay the problem if you infinitely store paths on a long-running server application.

Comment: @sorifiend Thank you for your comment. My problem is that the heap memory is not properly garbage collected, and because the worker coroutines are running indefinetly the variables are never cleared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worker pool can be automatically handled by the coroutine scope with an appropriate dispatcher.

If the image upload does blocking operations, you might want to use the IO dispatcher, like so: `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(5))`. I have omitted the `SupervisorJob` because you do not need it for the parent coroutine that will be created in `createWorkerGroup()`, but for the ones created *by* it. Don't forget to create the logic for cancelling the `CoroutineScope` when it is no longer needed.

After that, you can launch coroutines at will with no performance overhead, in the same place you did before:

```kotlin
@PostConstruct
fun createWorkerGroup() {
    coroutineScope.launch{
        supervisorScope {
            channel.consumeEach {
                launch {
                    uploadImage(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the correct approach for creating and using the worker pool, but you will need to test it in order to see if it eliminates the `OutOfMemoryError`. You might also want to try reducing the channel's capacity. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I couldn't use Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(5) even tho my kotlin.x.coroutines is version 1.6.3.

Comment: It just says no reference found. Do you know how I could solve this problem?

My heap is now properly garbage collected but it creates more than 5 coroutines.

Comment: `import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers` should include `limitedParallelism()`. Find more about it at https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-dispatcher/limited-parallelism.html. Note that the API is still experimental, so you need to annotate its usage with `@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)`. If the error persists, try invalidating the caches/restarting IntelliJ IDEA. Make sure to mark the answer as the solution if everything works, for other people to use it :)

Comment: I had to update my Kotlin Plugin, now it works. I need to add the limitedParallelism on the supervisorScope

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Halex for the help, here is my Kotlin coroutine worker pool with proper garbage collection

```kotlin
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
private val superVisorScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(5))
@PostConstruct
fun createWorkerGroup() {
    coroutineScope.launch {
        superVisorScope.launch {
            channel.consumeEach {
                launch {
                    uploadImage(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    coroutineScope.cancel()
}
```